# delete imap folder using Mailkit

Tags: c#, imap, mailkit

I am using the Mailkit for .net and am having trouble to delete a IMAP-folder that I created by Code. This is my sample code:
Created the folder like this:

```
var personal = Program.Client.GetFolder (Program.Client.PersonalNamespaces[0]);
            var mailkit = personal.Create("mailkit", false);
            var archive = mailkit.Create("archive", true);
            var flagged = mailkit.Create("flagged", true);
...
```

Tried to delete the Folder again like this:

```
    var temp = Program.Client.GetFolder("mailkit");
    temp.Delete();
```

Get an FolderNotFoundException, but the folder is still there?
Need a little help or tip how to do ...
(Sorry for this bad english :))

Comment: Do you get the exception in the Delete() call or the GetFolder() call?

Answer (score 0):

`Program.Client.GetFolder("mailkit");` is throwing a `FolderNotFoundException` because the folder doesn't exist. You need to provide the full path of the folder to `ImapClient.GetFolder(string path)`, but instead you have only provided the folder's name.

Here's how to get the "mailkit" folder:

```
var personal = Program.Client.GetFolder (Program.Client.PersonalNamespaces[0]);
var mailkit = personal.GetSubfolder ("mailkit");
```